# How to redirect to a VF page with a VF button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, controller-extension, button-overrides

I have a mySObject__c and a page mySObject_Button_Page with

```
<apex:page standardController="mySObject__c" extensions="mySObject_Button_Extension"
  title="{!mySObject__c.Name}"
  tabStyle="mySObject__c"
  standardStylesheets="true"
  action="{!doAction}"
>
```

.
I want to be redirected at this page after a button (which is represented by the same VF page) on mySObject__c's Detail page is pressed.

```
public PageReference doAction() {
  return new PageReference(Page.mySObject_Button_Page.getUrl());
}
```

In this case I get

```
An internal server error has occurred
```

. OK. Trying

```
public PageReference doAction() {
  return new PageReference(Page.mySObject_Button_Page.getUrl() + '?id=' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
}
```

I this case I get another error:

```
Formula Expression is required on the action attributes
```

.
I'm lost.

Comment: I think I understood what is the problem. When I hit the button it redirects to the page. When it come to page it... one more time redirects to itself. And loop repeats.

Comment: ok. It was really weird. When you create a button, you specify a page TO WHICH user is redirected. No need in redirection on button's page. I must have been very drunk to think in that way and ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added it as a custom button on your object, you don't even need extension code. You can use the `$Action` [Global Variable](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_action.htm).

```
<apex:page standardController="MySObject"
    action="{$URLFOR($Action.MySObject__c.MyAction, MySObject__c.id)}">
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I want to be redirected to the same page, which is used for button. And then there will be some logic. I don't want to create two separate pages.

Comment: Ended up with page for button <apex:page standardController="MySObject__c" action="{!URLFOR($Page.MyPage)}?id={!MySObject__c.Id}" ></apex:page>

Answer (score 0):

The expression `Page.mySObject_Button_Page` is a factory (something that creates) page references. So in the simplest case you can go to that page from an action like this:

```
public PageReference doAction() {
    return Page.mySObject_Button_Page;
}
```

If you want to add to the query string you can do that like this:

```
public PageReference doAction() {
    PageReference pr = Page.mySObject_Button_Page;
    pr.getParameters().put('id', ...);
    return pr;
}
```

Also note that returning null leaves you on the current page. I'm not exactly clear how many pages are involved in your case, but if its only one you could do this:

```
public PageReference doAction() {
    return null;
}
```

but that effectively does nothing.

Sometimes this pattern is useful for a page action:

```
public PageReference doAction() {

    // Run some code here

    // Carry on to the page that was initially requested
    return null;
}
```